# My Pygame sprite won't appear. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have been trying to make a little game using Pygame. This is my first time using Pygame and I have looked at many tutorials, but my sprite still won't appear. It only shows a black line. How can I fix it?

```
Xcord = 0
grey = (192,192,192)

import pygame, random, time

pygame.init()

import time

Color_line=(0,0,0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 500])
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

import pygame

grey = (192,192,192)
playerWidth = 50
playerHeight = 50
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, grey, playerWidth, playerHeight):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([50, 50])
        self.image.fill(grey)
        self.image.set_colorkey(grey)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, grey, [0, 0, playerWidth, playerHeight])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

player = Player(grey, 50, 50)
player.rect.x = Xcord
player.rect.y = 400

def update(Player):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.update(Player)
        player.rect.x = Xcord
        player.rect.y = 400

all_sprites_list.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    all_sprites_list.update()

    pygame.draw.line(screen,Color_line,(0,500),(1000,500), 75)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    Xcord =+ 50
    if Xcord == 400:
        Xcord == 0

pygame.quit()
```

I am kind of trying to make something similar to Google Chrome's [no Wi-Fi dinosaur game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Game).

Comment: Don't take this badly - your code is a mess on several levels - it's ok since you are learning. I think resources like this tutorial can be of much greater help than any Q&A here in this case -> https://kidscancode.org/blog/2016/08/pygame_1-2_working-with-sprites/

Comment: you have big mess. You should put all `import` at the beginning, next all classes and fuctinons, and later global variables and later `pygame.init()` and other code. See more [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Pyhon Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`. Maybe you forgot to run some code.

Comment: you have soo big mess that you import the same module two times, and you define the same `grey` two times. And you define `all_sprites_list` two times.

Comment: if you have class `Player` then use `player.rect.x` instead of `Xcoord`. If you change only `Xcoord` then player will not move because you have to change directly `player.rect.x` - don't waste time for changing `xcoord` and running `update()` if you can change directly `player.rect.x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few mistakes.

**First:** you `fill` sprite with `GRAY` and you use `set_key` on `GRAY`, so the sprite is transparent and simply you can't see the sprite.

**Second:** the code runs very fast and the sprite leaves the window and you can't see the sprite.

**Third:** in the code `if Xcord == 400: Xcord == 0`, you need `= 0` instead of `== 0` - and this is why the sprite leaves the window and never go back to position `(0, 400)`

---

Another problem is the big mess in the code - you even run some code two times.

---

My version with many changes.

```
# PEP8: all imports at start.
# PEP8: every module on a separate line
import pygame
import random
import time

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CAS_NAMES`

GRAY = (192, 192, 192)
RED  = (255,   0,   0)

# --- classes ---  # PEP8: `CamelCaseName`

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, weight):  # you don't need prefix `player` in variables in class `Player`
        super().__init__()   # Python 3 method for running a function from the original class
        self.color = color

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, weight])
        self.image.fill(color)
        #self.image.set_colorkey(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += 5

        if self.rect.x >= 400:
            self.rect.x = 0

# --- main ---

color_line = (0,0,0)  # PEP8: spaces around `=`, space after `,`

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000, 500])

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

player_width  = 50
player_weight = 50

player = Player(RED, 50, 400, 50, 50)  # color, x, y, width, height
all_sprites_list.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # - only updates -

    all_sprites_list.update()

    # - only draws -

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.draw.line(screen, color_line, (0, 500), (1000, 500), 75)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(30)  # Slow down to 30 FPS (frames per seconds)

pygame.quit()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)